# Using Samsung Earbuds as Headset on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, microphone

I've been able to pair my Samsung Earbuds with my system and can listen to audio through them, but can't get them to work for input.

When they pair, the Bluetooth Manager shows them as "headset" and when I click on them under Settings->Bluetooth I similarly see "Type Headset".

In Settings->Sound I can choose them for Output Device, but for configuration it says `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` and while it looks like I can choose `Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)` it doesn't seem to stay on that if I navigate away and back to settings->sound.

Input Device shows other options but not my Galaxy Earbuds.

In PulseAudio, they do not show on the Input Devices tab, and in the configuration tab it's much like sound settings, in that it says `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` but here the HSP option says unavailable `Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (unavailable)`

Any ideas?